# C#/MVC - How to loop through Multiple Files (from a file input), when the form contains multiple file inputs?

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor

Here's my HTML:

```
<input id="openbox_actual" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="file" name="videoFile" style="display: none;" />
<input id="openbox_actual2" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="file" accept="image/*" name="screenShots" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;" />
```

As shown above, one file input takes a video file, and the other takes **multiple** image files.

Here's the controller:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["videoFile"];
HttpPostedFileBase screens = Request.Files["screenShots"];
```

From the code above, I can access/upload "file" just fine.

However, I can't figure out how to access all the files inside "screens" **ONLY**.

I've seen many examples where people iterate through the "HttpPostedFileCollection", but that contains ALL the files, in EVERY file input.  I just want all the files from the "screenShots" multiple file input.

Extra points if anyone knows how to "limit" the number of files to 8.  (e.g. Where the "screenShots" file input only allows you to upload 8 files total.

Thanks,
You guys are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetKey` to get the name for a given index.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < this.Request.Files.Count; i++ ) {

    String key = this.Request.Files.GetKey( i );

    if( key == "screenShots" ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

You could do this as a kind of preprocessing step you can re-use elsewhere:

```
public static Dictionary<String,List<HttpPostedFileBase>> GetFilesAsDictionary( HttpFileCollection files ) {

    Dictionary<String,List<HttpPostedFileBase>> dict = Dictionary<String,List<HttpPostedFileBase>>;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < files.Count; i++ ) {
        String key = file.GetKey( i );

        List<HttpPostedFileBase> list;

        if( !dict.TryGetValue( key, out list ) ) {
            dict.Add( key, list = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>() );
        }

        list.Add( files[i] );
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction() {

    Dictionary<String,List<HttpPostedFileBase>> files = UploadUtility.GetFilesAsDictionary( this.Request.Files );

    HttpPostedFileBase video = files["videoFile"][0];
    Int32 screenshotCount = files["screenShots"].Count;
    if( screenshotCount > 8 ) {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError( "", "Limit of 8 screenshots at a time." );
        return this.View( new VideModel() );
    }

    foreach(HttpPostedFileBase screenshot in files["screenShots"]) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you nailed it!  Crushed it out of the park.  Way to go, and GREAT response time!  If we were playing baseball, and I needed a ringer to blast one out of the park, you would be my first pick.  Thanks again.  :-)